# Oracle APEX timeout interrupts the running of a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, timeout, apex

There is a long (1 hour) stored procedure that stops running due to a timeout (after 14 minutes 41 seconds every time).
My questions:

1. Is it possible that the apex admin settings (Timeout Settings) do not take effect before restarting the Windows server?
2. How can I set, that the page don't timeout after 14 minutes and 41 seconds (but let it be e.g. 2 hours)
3. How can I set the stored procedure to keep running after the timeout.

Windows Server 2019 Standard
ORACLE ver.: 19.3.0.0.0
APEX ver.: 22.1.0

I tried from 5 workstations with the same result.
I tried with the same version of APEX running on another (linux) machine, there, the running of the stored procedure is not interrupted after the timeout.

Comment: you need to submit it as a job, no?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, this is a stored procedure that is launched from the apex page (a process) by pressing a button (submit) 
Although it don't depends on the sp, because it does the same for any test program longer than 14:41

Comment: Meantime, I was able to restart the server, point 1 cannot be the cause (which was to be expected) but the question of section (1) or (2) remains...

Answer (score 0):

Anything running that long is a threat to (any) web-based application.  APEX (like pretty much anything that talks to a database) does its database work via a connection pool.  Thus you always have "n" connections that serves all requests.

If you have a long running task, then you've locked up 1 of those "n" connections, and similarly, any user getting frustrated could click the mouse "n" times and voila... your connection pool is totally consumed.

For long running stuff, look at using DBMS_SCHEDULER or DBMS_JOB to have that process run asynchronously so that control is returned to your APEX app.  It can then monitor or show the user the progress.

On the latest version of APEX, this can all be done declaratively with background processing now baked into the product.

Comment: I understand, thanks.
The process can only be started once, no matter how many times the button is pressed by n users. The stored procedure does not restart until the last process is finished.